# Using a regular expression to validate credit card month and year

Tags: c#, .net, model, umbraco, data-annotations

I am having some trouble validating a couple of fields in my model namely the expiry month and year for a credit card.

The pattern I require for the month is obviously:

1-12

The pattern I require for the year is:

0-99

I have setup my regular expressions in my model as follows:

```
        [UmbracoRequired("Booking.Validation.Required")]
        [UmbracoRegularExpression("Booking.Validation.CreditMonthFormat", "[1-12]")]
        public int booking_expirymonth { get; set; }

        [UmbracoRequired("Booking.Validation.Required")]
        [UmbracoRegularExpression("Booking.Validation.CreditYearFormat", "[0-99]")]
        public int booking_expiryyear { get; set; }
```

The date selection is made via two select fields in the view which pass through:

Month

01, 02, 03 , 04 etc

Year

01, 02, 03

However when this gets into the controller it strips the leading zero. I'm not too bothered about this as I can handle it later but the problem is even with the values passed through being completely valid, the model is always deemed invalid when it reaches the !ModelState.IsValid check.

I look through the code in VS and can see that it is receiving "17" for the year suggesting it is a string but when i view the value of the actual model value it is treated as an int.

Can anyone help me out with this as it is driving me nuts.

Comment: I would just save them as a string and parse them when I need the values. Leading zero's will never be saved.

Comment: Like I said I'm not really bothered about the leading zeros being there or not. I'm more concerned with it no validating correctly when the values passed are perfectly valid. I also don't want to remove the validation from the model as this is the way it should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 01-12 use following regex

```
0[1-9]|1[0-2]
```

This will work for 01,02,03...12

For 1-12 use

```
[2-9]|1[0-2]?
```

This will work for 1,2..

& for years from 01-99

```
^(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$
```

Comment: I have tested these here http://regexhero.net/tester/ an unfortunately the last one for the years does not work

Comment: what is your test string?

Comment: All of the numbers in sequence. I have actually found the idea for the years on my own : [0-9]{1,2}

Comment: @jezzipin that's great.

Comment: @user2148124 you can replace `[0-9]{1,2}` to `\d\d` for your case.